# How to access other controllers in your application?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have an application with several controllers dedicated each to its own part, say, "news", "articles" and "shop". They are not connected to each other, but they should be, as I need to insert data from them, like news related to current shop category. I have not found a clean way to access controllers other than the current one that is handling the request.

The structure of the modules is:

- `Site.pm` is the main project file.
- `Articles.pm` handles articles.
- `News.pm` handles news.
- `Shop.pm` handles shop.

`Site.pm` loads each of the above dynamically from an array of module names and calls its `register` function to set routes up and other things at startup. Articles, news, etc all take content from database, and it is rendered as inline template, thus, I can't just take related news and slam them into the stash, as not all entries in shop might even need that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a theoretical answer without code.

You probably have the database stuff decoupled from the actual controllers as models. That's good.

So let's assume we're in the shop and we want to show news related to the current product. There are at least two ways to do that.

1. You call your models directly. Your model for news provides a way to get the news for a product. You do that in the shop controller that displays the product page. This controller needs to put the stuff in the stash so the templates can access it.
2. You create a method in your news controller that is not accessible from the outside. You make it take a product id and find related news articles and populate them into the stash. You forward to it from your product page controller in the shop controller. Afterwards, the product page controller continues. This is the *more decoupled* way.

In both cases, your shop template includes another template that knows how to deal with the stuff in the stash for displaying news. You might be able to recycle a news template here.

Comment: "You create a method in your news controller... You forward to it" -- that's how I WANT it to be, but I don't know HOW TO access a different controller from current.

Comment: @ZzZombo It seems like what I suggested does not work in Mojolicious. I asked in #mojo on irc.perl.org and Sri, the author of Mojolicious said _there is no forward like in catalyst_, _it's incompatible with all the async features_, _we recommend you abstract out shared functionality into helpers_ and provided http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Adding-a-plugin-to-your-application as a reference point.

Comment: That's too bad. The point of different controllers is exactly to separate parts of application, but adding helpers for shared functions defeats the whole system design. I might as well keep the whole project in just `Site.pm`.

Comment: Controllers are not intended to be "thick," controllers are supposed to be a thin layer between the request, the view logic, and the model logic. This is pretty canonical MVC design.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Mojolicious but IMO this is the best approach -

Your Site controller should send GET requests to whatever other controllers it wants and these controllers should return JSON data which can then be rendered at the client side. Take a look [Rendering JSON](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Rendering-JSON). Hope that helps.

Comment: No. That doesn't sound healthy. That's in fact a kind of not so micro service architecture where all services are in the same application. You don't want to do that on small app.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, coding-blood, and a lot of shame for my code, I advise:
each method in a controller should only call a single function and pass the results to the template. This is somehow similar to the answer of @simbabque.

This will help you later testing the controller, writing API instead of providing html templates, even change the framework completely (as long as it is Perl).

So, I would add an optional layer between the Controller and the Models:

1. `$t->get('/books/:id')->to('books#get')`
2. `sub Books::get{ my $self = shift; my $book = FBooks::get($self->param('id')); # plus template call }`
3. `sub FBooks::get{ # here you call your Model }`
4. `# your Model calls your DB`

You provide the FBooks::get only then, when you need to make multiple calls to your model/s (maybe this is not a perfect example, but I hope you get my point). I prefer this instead of an army of helpers.  If there is any other better way, I am happy to learn it.